# Left Join Sum and Comparison

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a stock buying program for which there can exist multiple sell transactions per buy transaction. I am trying to create a query that will pull up any stocks for which I still have shares invested. For Example, if I buy 50 shares of a stock and sell 20 one day and 10 on another, I should still have 20 shares left over.  I have done most of the hard work but I swear I am missing something small. My current query will not pull a result if it does not exist in the sell_transaction table. In my example, that is transaction_id 3 in buy_transactions which should return 100 shares but returns nothing. The following code can be put into SQL Fiddle and worked on.

***Schema***

```
CREATE TABLE `buy_transactions` (
`buy_transactions_id` int(11),
`buy_transaction_date` date,
`symbol` varchar(50),
`shares` int(11),
`price_per_shae` decimal(10,6));

insert into buy_transactions values (1,'2016-01-25','A',15,100.000000);
insert into buy_transactions values (2,'2014-03-16','A',20,30.000000);
insert into buy_transactions values (3,'2016-01-15','AA',100,60.000000);
insert into buy_transactions values (4,'2015-05-05','AA',500,60.000000);

CREATE TABLE `sell_transactions` (
`sell_transactions_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`sell_transaction_date` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`shares` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`price` decimal(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
`related_buy_transaction` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`sell_transactions_id`));

insert into sell_transactions values (1, '2016-01-25', 5, 120.000000, 1);
insert into sell_transactions values (2, '2016-01-25', 10, 130.000000, 1);
insert into sell_transactions values (3, '2016-01-25', 10, 50.000000, 2);
insert into sell_transactions values (4, '2016-01-15', 500, 61.000000, 4);
```

***Current Query***

```
select bt.buy_transactions_id, bt.symbol, bt.shares - rt.SoldShares as remaining_stock
from buy_transactions bt
left join
    (select related_buy_transaction, sum(shares) as SoldShares from sell_transactions group by related_buy_transaction) rt
on bt.buy_transactions_id = rt.related_buy_transaction
where bt.shares - rt.SoldShares > 0;
```

***Current Query Results***

```
buy_transactions_id     symbol  remaining_stock
2                       A       10
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73524/1)

Comment: and desired/expected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `coalesce`:

```
select bt.buy_transactions_id 
     , bt.symbol
     , bt.shares - coalesce(rt.SoldShares, 0) as remaining_stock
from buy_transactions bt
left join
( select related_buy_transaction
       , sum(shares) as SoldShares
  from sell_transactions
  group by related_buy_transaction ) rt on bt.buy_transactions_id = rt.related_buy_transaction
where bt.shares > coalesce(rt.SoldShares, 0);
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73524/18)

Comment: Thank you. Another question on the side. This is my first system like this. Do you know of a better way to handle this type of transaction?